# How to create unique plane with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How to create a unique plane, with (x , y ,z) as center and a vector as normal, in PostGIS?

I already saw "Make3DBox" function, but it does not make a unique one.

Comment: Does "ST_3DMakeBox" create a unique box?

Comment: Unique in what context?

Comment: @Jakub Kania I mean this function create more than one plane which involve just two points in 3d coordinate, but I want to create a unique one.

Comment: Well, that creates a cube rather than a single plane. `ST_ConvexHull` would be better but that's still not quite it.